# In Vim, how do you repeat multiple substitutions for multiple files?

Tags: vim, substitution

I have 10 files, each containing 'apple' and 'red'. I want to change 'apple' to 'pear' and change 'red' to 'green' across all 10 files.

My current method is typing out this find and replace command `:%s/apple/pear/g` (and the same for red to green) in each file. How do I save these two substitutions and have them apply to the 10 files. More generally, how do I do this more efficiently?

I'm new to vim and am not sure whether to look into command history or vim register or something else.

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### The basics

Vim does not come with a project-wide find & replace. It comes down to doing the following steps:

- Create a list of files you wish to work upon
- Run your command on each file on the list

#### The substitution

You can run multiple commands one after another with the `|`.

Example

```
:s/apple/pear/ | s/red/green/
```

Since you updating these files it might be best to also `:write` or `:update` the file as well

```
:s/apple/pear/ | s/red/green/ | update
```

Substitution flags:

- Use `g` for "global" or doing multiple substitutions per line
- Use `e` to suppress errors. We need this as a file may have `apple` but no `red` for example

`:s` takes a range like `1,3` to work on lines 1 through line 3. `$` represents the last line number. An entire file is `1,$`. Use `%` as shorthand for `1,$`

```
:%s/apple/pear/ge | %s/red/green/ge | update
```

Thoughts:

- May want to use `\<` & `\>` around your patterns. E.g. `red` pattern as `red` can be in different words like `predicate`
- May want to take case into consideration

#### Argument List

If you started Vim with the list of files you wish to work on then these files are already in the Argument List

```
$ vim file*.txt
```

You can supply arguments after vim is started via `:args` or `:argadd`. e.g. `:args file*.txt`

Use `:args` to see the argument list

Use `:argdo {cmd}` to run your command, `{cmd}` over all files in the argument list

#### Quickfix List

Often you want to search for a pattern in a group of files and then do a replacement on those matches. Vim's `:vimgrep` & `:grep` search for files and put these positions into the Quickfix List

```
:vimgrep /apple\|red/ **/*.txt
```

You can see the quickfix list with `:copen` or `:clist`.

Use `:cdo {cmd}`/`:cfdo {cmd}` to run a command, `{cmd}`, over every position/file in the quickfix list

```
:cfdo %s/apple/pear/ge | %s/red/green/ge | update
:cdo s/apple/pear/e | s/apple/pear/e | update
```

#### Leveling up `:grep`

`:grep` will use `'grepprg'` & `'grepformat'` to execute and read the output of program like `grep` (used by default on linux). This is often faster than `:vimgrep` at the expense of using a different regex syntax.

Instead of using `grep` as your `'grepprg'`, you can use something like [ripgrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep) or [ag the silver searcher](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher) which are both often even faster than plain `grep`.

Example of config options for ripgrep:

```
set grepprg=rg\ --vimgrep
set grepformat=%f:%l:%c:%m
```

Now you can do `:grep 'apple\|red'` to populate the quickfix list

You can even take this further if you want by [running `:grep` in a subshell](https://gist.github.com/romainl/56f0c28ef953ffc157f36cc495947ab3)

#### Other lists?!?

Vim has other lists like: buffer, window, tabs, location list. These have an associated "do" command with them: `:bufdo`, `:windo`, `:tabdo`, `:ldo`

#### Abolish's `:Subvert`

Although, no plugins are needed to do such substitutions across files, it might be handy to know about Tim Pope's [vim-abolish](https://github.com/tpope/vim-abolish) plugin. Especially if you have many of these substitutions and/or have casing issues. Abolish's `:Subvert`/`:S` command can reduce your substitution commands to 1 command

```
:%S/{apple,red}/{pear,green}/gw
```

This will convert `apple` -> `pear` and `red` -> `green` due to their positions inside of the curly braces.

Use `:Subvert`'s `w` flag to only substitute words. Subvert also will handle cases

#### Vimcasts

Here are some [Vimcasts](http://vimcasts.org/) episodes which are related:

- [Meet the arglist](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/meet-the-arglist/)
- [Populating the arglist](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/populating-the-arglist/)
- [Using :argdo to change multiple files](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/using-argdo-to-change-multiple-files/)
- [Search multiple files with :vimgrep](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/search-multiple-files-with-vimgrep/)
- [Project-wide find and replace](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/project-wide-find-and-replace/) (note `:cdo`/`:cfdo` are in Vim now)
- [Supercharged substitution with :Subvert](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/supercharged-substitution-with-subvert/)

#### TL;DR

Search with `:vimgrep` and run your substitutions with `:cfdo`

```
:vimgrep /apple\/red/ *.txt
:cfdo %s/apple/pear/ge | %s/red/green/ge | update
```

#### For more help

Read more using Vim's help system

```
   :h argument-list
   :h :argdo
   :h :args
   :h quickfix.txt
   :h :cdo
   :h :cfdo
   :h :vimgrep
   :h :grep
   :h 'grepprg'
   :h 'grepformat'
```

Comment: Wow.  I am in awe of this answer.  It looks like a few hours of work there.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a command such as `:argdo` or `:bufdo` to repeat the same Ex command on many files. (See `:help :argdo`.)

For example, you can open your 10 files by passing them as arguments to Vim. If they're all `*.txt` files, you can use:

```
$ vim *.txt
```

Then you can use `:argdo` to repeat the operation on all the files Vim got as arguments:

```
:argdo %s/apple/pear/eg | update
```

Of notice here, I'm adding a `| update` at the end of the operation, in order to save the file after performing the substitution, for each of the files. That's important, otherwise `:argdo` will error out before moving to the next file. (See `:help :update`, it's similar to `:w` but only saves when there are modifications. The `|` is a command separator for Ex commands in Vim.)

An alternative to using `| update` is to use `:set hidden`, which allows you to start editing another file before moving on to the next one. (See `:help 'hidden'`.) You can later use `:wall` to write all files once you're done with the modifications everywhere.

Finally, I'm passing an extra `/e` flag to the substitution, to prevent it from generating an error if there is no match to replace. (See `:help :s_e`.)

You can also chain multiple commands (such as substitution commands) by using `|` as a separator. For example:

```
:set hidden
:argdo %s/apple/pear/eg | %s/red/green/eg
:wall
```

Answer (score 2):

The [quickfix-reflector](https://github.com/stefandtw/quickfix-reflector.vim) allows you to edit results in the quickfix and apply those edits back to the original files.

1. Use `:grep` as usual to search your project for matches (`:grep apple -R .`) -- or whatever method you want to populate the quickfix.
2. Edit the quickfix. (`:%s/apple/pear/ge | %s/red/green/ge`)
3. Save the quickfix buffer. (`:w`)
4. Now all your files are modified (or the quickfix shows ERROR next to lines that it couldn't update).

Normally, the quickfix isn't 'modifiable', but quickfix-reflector will modify that setting and add a hook to propagate changes on save. There are several alternative plugins offering similar functionality and it's a big change to your workflow!